# Pandas pivot_table -- index values extended through rows

Tags: pandas, indexing, pivot-table

I'm trying to tidy some data, specifically by taking two columns "measure" and "value" and making more columns for each unique value of measure.

So far I have some python (3) code that reads in data and pivots it to the form that I want--roughly. This code looks like so:

```
import pandas as pd
#Load the data
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\User\Documents\example data.csv")

#Pivot the dataframe
df_pivot = df.pivot_table(index=['Geography Type', 'Geography Name', 'Week Ending',
 'Item Name'], columns='Measure', values='Value')

print(df_pivot.head())
```

This outputs:

```
Measure                                               X   Y   Z
Geography Type Geography Name Week Ending Item Name            
Type 1         Total US       1/1/2018    Item A     57  51  16
                                          Item B     95  37  17
                              1/8/2018    Item A     92   8  32
                                          Item B     36  49  54
Type 2         Region 1       1/1/2018    Item A     78  46  88
```

This is almost perfect, but for my work I need to put this file in software and for the software to read the data correctly it needs values for each of the rows, so I need the columns values for each of those indexes to extend through the rows, like so:

```
Measure                                               X   Y   Z
Geography Type Geography Name Week Ending Item Name            
Type 1         Total US       1/1/2018    Item A     57  51  16
Type 1         Total US       1/1/2018    Item B     95  37  17
Type 1         Total US       1/8/2018    Item A     92   8  32
Type 1         Total US       1/8/2018    Item B     36  49  54
Type 2         Region 1       1/1/2018    Item A     78  46  88
```

and so on.

Comment: It already does, you just see it this way because of how pandas displays it. Run `df.reset_index()` and you'll see.

Comment: Ah, got it. I had that in my initial code but must have been overwriting it somehow, i think by not assigning it as a new object after doing so? regardless, using this method and assigning it to df_new fixed everything, including the format of the output file. Thank you!